# How to order by Levenshtein distance?

Tags: postgresql, order-by

I want to order a table according to a char field using Levenshtein distance or similar because some entries may contain underscores or grammar errors.

It is a table with all the books I plan to read and it contains repeated entries I need list all the entries ordered by the field name, It should take the previous row and find the closest text.

This is a failed attempt I made:

```
SELECT name, 
levenshtein(substring(name from 1 for 200), lag(name) OVER (PARTITION BY name)) 
FROM books WHERE name <> '';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell us what the "failed attempt" means. But something like this should work:

```
with ldist as (
   select name, 
          levenshtein(substring(name,1,200), lag(name) OVER (order by name))  as distance
   FROM books 
   WHERE name <> ''
) 
select * 
from ldist
order by distance;
```

you don't want `partition by name` because that essentially puts every name into a single group and thus there is no "previous" row to.

As you you want the "previous" row based on the ordering of the `name` column, you need an `order by name` in the window definition.

Comment: Thanks, it help me to understand better 'partition by' but it does not work like I want. I need the the order to be the Levenshtein distance relative from the previous row, this query orders the absolute distance. For example list 'AAA' then list its closest match 'AAB' then it list the closest match to 'AAB'. Maybe it is not possible to archive

Comment: The levensthein distance **is** calculated between the name of the "current" row and the name of the "previous" row, where "previous is defined by the order on the name.

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem is the 'order by distance', it orders the list from 0 to 58. The list as I want should look 0,1,2,3,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0.

Comment: Another difference is the "order by name", for example I have a book that starts " David Sklansky" and another that starts "David Sklansky" without the space, if I order them by name they wont be compared to each other. Maybe it is my mistake to use levenshtein in the first place.

Comment: What about using an `order by soundex(name)` for the window function?

Comment: That would be ideal but soundex does not work for long sentences. Indeed I could use a simple `select * from books order by soundex(name);` but it does not work for senteces.